# Failing to apply style in validation errors

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I am learning asp.net mvc 5. I am trying to style the validation errors, but I fail. This is my `CSS`(in the `Style.css` file) that is supposed to style the `validation errors`.

```
.field-validation-error {
    color: red;
}

.input-validation-error {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

And here is how I create my validation message with razor syntax:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Customer.Name)
```

But this is the result i get:

[image: application style in action]

As you can see no styling has been applied in the validation errors.

I found some questions here in stackoverflow with that kind of problem, but none of the solutions actually helped me. Thank you !

Comment: Add `!important` in your css. For example, `color: red !important;`

Comment: @BasantaMatia it didn't worked ! I get the same result.

Comment: It should work. Clear your browser cache and reload again and check.

Comment: @BasantaMatia unbelievable !!! After cleaning the cache it works !! Thank you very very much !!

Comment: So glad that it helped you:) To help others you can accept my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can override default css by using **!important** property. For example,

```
.field-validation-error {
  color: red !important;
 }
.input-validation-error {
  border: 2px solid red !important;
 }
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

While overriding css rule with `!important` will work, I would advise not to use that because it would be almost impossible to override those styles in case that you will need it in the future.

Instead create a custom css class (for example `my-validation-error`) and add the following css rule:

```
.field-validation-error.my-validation-error {
  color: red;
}
```

Then simply use this class in validation message helper:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Customer.Name,  new { @class ="my-validation-error"})
```